# Access services on k8s on prem

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 virtual machines (ubuntu 18 lts) on my local pc: 1 is master and 2 are nodes. I was able to install kubernetes and also to setup my application.

My application consist of 3 parts: database, backend and frontend. For each of these parts I've created and deployed services. I want to expose the FE service outside the cluster to be able to access it from one of the nodes.

The service description looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fe-deployment
  labels:
    run: fe-srv
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8085
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: fe
  type: NodePort
```

The ouput of

> kubectl get node -o wide

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8node1      Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.0   172.17.199.105   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   5.0.0-29-generic   docker://18.9.7
k8node2      Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.0   172.17.199.110   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   5.0.0-29-generic   docker://18.9.7
```

> kubectl get service -o wide

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
be-deployment   ClusterIP   10.96.169.225   <none>        8080/TCP         2d22h   app=be
db-deployment   ClusterIP   10.110.14.88    <none>        3306/TCP         2d22h   app=db
fe-deployment   NodePort    10.104.211.32   <none>        8085:32476/TCP   2d21h   app=fe
```

I would have expected that using one node IP and the node port to be able to access my FE from browser, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing? How to access my FE from outside the cluster?

**Edit**

Based on the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), NodePort service type should:

> Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting NodeIP:NodePort

I understand that I will access my service from outside of the cluster using node IP and static port. From the node IP statement I understand that it refers to the machine (the VM in my case) IP.

**Later Edit**

I've checked the firewall and it seems that is disable on all my machines:

> sudo ufw status
>
> Status: inactive

**Later later edit**

As I told in a comment, trying to telnet to IPv4 address didn't work. Trying with IPv6 does work on localhost and also using the ethernet interface IPv6 IP.

The netstat output is:

```
 netstat -6 -a | grep 324
 tcp6       1      0 [::]:32476              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Despite the fact that it should work (based on the information I read on internet) it doesn't work with IPv4. Is there a way to change this?

**Later later later edit**

It seems that this is a [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66766)

Comment: what is meant by doesnt work? please paste the error. can you reach the node ip othervise , can u login into that node and see the nodeport by doing `ss -tln`

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan I can do all of that. The output of ss -tln is `LISTEN   0  128 *:32476`

Comment: Can u telnet to that port? Maybe it's blocked in firewall

Comment: I tried to use `telnet 172.17.199.105 32476` and I receive connection refused

Comment: so something is blocking u from accessing that port.

Comment: and maybe ur front end is not able to handle connections , paste the log of front end pod while u try to access that port

Comment: the front end is able to handle. using the pod IP and I was able to access and use(login) my front end

Comment: I am having the same issue. It appears that NodePort is listening on an IPv6 address only: `netstat -al | grep 32476` will output only the following: `tcp6  0  0 [::]:32476  [::]:*  LISTEN ` There is no ipv4 address. Attempting to curl with: `curl http://192.168.3.105:32476` results in no response.

Comment: @florin I will need the following information:
1. What virtualization software are you using and what version?
2. In virtualization software what network mode is being used?
3. Which kubernetes network plugin is being used and what version?

Comment: @PiotrMalec 1. Hyper-V Manager Version: 10.0.17763.1 
3.I'm using calico version 3.9
2. I'm not sure how to check this. Any hints?
I updated the question with a [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66766) to github. It seems it's a bug

Comment: @florin, by default dual-stack networks for calico version 3.9 is turned off. `# Disable IPv6 on Kubernetes. - name: FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT value: "false"` according to manifest file used for installation https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.9/manifests/calico.yaml . You might want to verify the calico configuration by running command `kubectl describe pod -n kube-system calico-node-xxxxx` and look for line `FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `EXTERNAL-IP` for `fe` service  as IP address if node.

Then you can check : `curl -k http://EXTERNAL-IP:PORT`

EXTERNAL-IP is Node of IP adress Server.

Comment: I would have expected that kubernetes assign external IP. As I see in some tutorials using AWS, the nodes have external IP. Is there some docs where it is stated that on premise you should add by hand external ip?

Comment: yes, please add by hand external ip is as ip address of node.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, due to you didn't defined `nodePort`, kubernetes randomly assigned port `32476` to your service. To access that service go to `<EXTERNAL-NODE-IP>:32476` [(kubernetes-docs)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

If you want to assign specific port, you need to define `nodePort` in service definition (example for ingress based on nginx):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30080
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
 selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: I don't have an external IP as you see in the commands output. I can assign one I would expected kubernetes to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You would not get an external IP when exposing service as a nodeport.

Exposing Service on a Nodeport means that your service would be available on externally via the NodeIP of any node in the cluster at a random port between 30000-32767(default behaviour) .

Each of the nodes in the cluster proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into the pod where your service is launched.

From your `kubectl get service -o wide` output:

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
fe-deployment   NodePort    10.104.211.32   <none>        8085:32476/TCP   2d21h   app=fe
```

We can find that port on which your service is exposed is port **`32476`**.

From Your `kubectl get node -o wide` output:

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8node1      Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.0   172.17.199.105   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   5.0.0-29-generic   docker://18.9.7
k8node2      Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.0   172.17.199.110   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   5.0.0-29-generic   docker://18.9.7
```

We can find that your node ips are: **`172.17.199.105`** and **`172.17.199.110`**

You can now access your service externally using `<Node-IP>:<Node-Port>`.

So in Your case these are **`172.17.199.105:32476`** and **`172.17.199.110:32476`** depending on which node you want to access Your service.

Additionally, if you want a fixed Node port, you can specify that in the yaml.

You need to make sure you add a security rule on your nodes to allow traffic on the particular port.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. This is my problem: when trying in browser to access 172.17.199.105:32476, I receive unable to connect. Now I'm trying to see if it's a firewall issue.

Comment: Be aware that Your network configuration of virtualization software that has 3 Virtual Machines running can also be in NAT mode. So if You are trying to access the service from outside of that network might need additional port forwarding.

Update:
I also recommend trying to ping first to check if the address can be resolved and is accessible.

Comment: I am logged in on one of the nodes and I'm trying using browser from that specific node